# jQuery - possible conflict?

Tags: jquery, html, conflict

Please see http://www.waggingtailz.com.au/

password: udolye

It appears as though the theme.js file is not 'working' - either an issue in laoding or more likely a conflict somewhere.

This results in the homepage image carousel or the drop-down menu not working.

In the source, this is the linked js file

```
 <script src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0213/6386/t/4/assets/theme.js?489" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

edit:

```
here is the function


    function updateCartDesc(data){
var $cartLinkText = $('#top-cartlink-text');


switch(data.item_count){
  case 0: 
    $cartLinkText.text('Your cart is empty');
    break;
  case 1:
    $cartLinkText.text('1 item');
    break;
  default:
    $cartLinkText.text(data.item_count+' items for ');
    break;
}
```

}

this is the shopify liquid markup that returns the total cart price

```
    {{ cart.total_price | money }}
```

I tried setting a variable but no luck. do you know if this is possible? Thanks

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid property id
http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0213/6386/t/4/assets/theme.js?491
Line 102

Answer (score 0):

Use the Chrome Debugger. There is a Syntax Error in theme.js

```
themejs:102 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {  themejs:102
```

On the line you can see

```
        $cartLinkText.text('1 item for '+{{ cart.total_price | money }});
```

This is not valid JS syntax. Looks more like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick respsonse. that's shopify mark-up language liquid.

Comment: sorry.. still going. is there anyway I can still get the cart total cost to be parsed. if I change it to

Comment: $cartLinkText.text('1 item for {{ cart.total_price | money }}'); then this appears as written, rather than shopify returning the correct figure

Comment: $cartLinkText.text('1 item for '+cart.total_price | money)    I thought this would work, but now the total doesn't update at all